# Keeping certain scale of OS layers while zooming

Tags: qgis, scale, ordnance-survey

On QGIS I have a WMS OS Premium Raster layer supplied by an external company. As I zoom in and out (i.e. change scale), the map changes to reflect the different OS map scales.

How can I stop this happening and ensure that, for example, the 1:10,000 scale OS map is displayed regardless of zoom/scale level in QGIS?

I've searched on the internet for a while and found no answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is really something to discuss with your data supplier. In general, OS recommend a fixed range of scales with their different datasets so that the map is usable across the full range of scales. That said there is nothing (except efficiency) to prevent you having a custom layer set up that provides you with OS data styled as if at the scale 1:10000 throughout your range of scales, however as you zoom out there is a chance of overloading the server as it will have too much data to draw.